# What does might mean RUNTIME0013?

Tags: wcf, runtime-error

When i trying to use my WCF client a get an error

```
RUNTIME0013: Failed to connect to 'http://localhost:8080....
```

So if client just cann't to connect to remote endpoint than error looks like
 `There was no endpoint listening at`

But what is RUNTIME0013 ? I cann't even google this kind of error.

Comment: This looks specific to your app.

Comment: @Simon Mourier  But i only call WCF service. This error thrown somewhere in WCF i think. What can be specific to my app?

Comment: WCF has nothing like that. It can be in your client or in the server (unlikely since the message says you can't connect, but one never knows, maybe the server connects itself too). Showing some code may help.